# Roundcube webmail can't receive Email

Tags: email, nas, pop3

I have a round cube webmail station that is installed inside Synology NAS. I can send Email. I am using the SMTP of our ISP.

My problem is I cannot receive Mail.

I know this is an issue in POP3 but I can't find it in synology. I open already the port 110 for POP3 in our zyxel router. But still I can't receive anything.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where are you getting your mail from? Your ISP? Gmail? Hotmail? What is your email provider? Your router shouldn't need any port forwarding set up as to my knowledge Synology will connect out and grab the email from the various email server that you set up.

Comment: Before I can receive mail, I just don't know what happened. I am getting my mail from Gmail. My email provider is the one I created in synology (www.mydomain.com/mail). In the SMTP settings I used the SMTP of our ISP so that I can send mail. I hope I answered your question and didn't mix it up. Thanks for reply!

Comment: You get your mail from GMail, but you send mail using your ISP SMTP server, not using Gmail's SMTP? Just to be clear, you are trying to get mail from your GMail email, or from your ISP email?

Comment: I am really sorry to confuse you as I am in how I ask questions :). I am sending mail (trying if I can receive mail inside www.client@mydomain.com in roundcube) using my Gmail account (www.myname@gmail.com). Now in my setting in SMTP in roundcube I am using the SMTP of our ISP, because of that I can send email to my gmail.

Comment: If you want your synology box to become a mail server and receive your client@mydomain.com emails, you need to have your MX record to your synology box.. at least that is the limit of my knowledge about this. The other option is to have each user to set up a POP account using roundcube to access their individual emails. Sorry I can't help any further with my limited knowledge. You may be able to get more help from Synology tech support than here.

Comment: I really appreciate your knowledge sir. Thank you for your giving time in answering my questions. It really helped a lot.